# Use vuex state in Vuetify.js plugin

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuetify.js

I'm getting very confused about calling a vuex state inside the Vuetify.js plugin.

My project is to translate a website based on the users preferred language. I've completely setup the translations with i18n. This project consists of 2 parts.

1. The translation based on JSON files (This is working just fine)
2. The translation of the Vuetify components based on the translations provided by Vuetify.

The 2nd point is where I get stuck.
According to the manual from Vuetify you need to import the needed language files inside the Vuetify.js plugin. This all works perfect.

But...I can only change it manually....

What I want to achieve is that the correct Vuetify language gets set based in the language set inside my vuex store.
Believe me, I've been search the internet for days and tried everything that I could find. But nothing seems to work. I can't seem to figure out how to call the vuex state inside the Vuetify.js plugin.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'

Vue.use(Vuetify)

import nl from 'vuetify/es5/locale/nl'
import fr from 'vuetify/es5/locale/fr'
import en from 'vuetify/es5/locale/en'

Vue.component('my-component', {
 methods: {
    changeLocale() {
        this.$vuetify.lang.current
    },
 },
})
export default new Vuetify({
 lang: {
    locales: { nl, en, fr },
    current: "nl",
},
})
```

So the state of `current` should be based on the state in my vuex store.

Here is my vuex store

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import createPersistedState from 'vuex-persistedstate'
import i18n, { selectedLocale } from './i18n'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    locale: selectedLocale
  },
  mutations: {
    updateLocale(state, newLocale) {
      state.locale = newLocale
    }
  },
  actions: {
    changeLocale({ commit }, newLocale) {
      i18n.locale = newLocale
      commit('updateLocale', newLocale)
    }
  },
  plugins: [createPersistedState()]
})
```

Who can point me in the right direct on who to go about this?

Comment: There is an example how to integrate Vue-i18n with Vuetify - https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/internationalization/#vue-i-18-n

Comment: @IVOGELOV This is where I refer to. My question is how to change "Current" based on the state in my vuex store. In other words...how to get the vuex state inside Vuetify.js

Comment: You should actually work in the opposite direction - how to get the `this.$vuetify.lang` object inside your `updateLocale` mutation so you can change its `current` property to the `newLocale`

Comment: @IVOGELOV and how do I do this? Sorry, learning

Comment: Well, the easiest way would be if you start sending `this.$vuetify` as an argument to your mutation.

Comment: @IVOGELOV But how?? Can you please give a solution in an answer?

Comment: @IVOGELOV Did you see the github?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217159/discussion-between-sonia-and-ivo-gelov).

Comment: I can not solve the problem for you by digging in the code on Github. My answer below already contains all the information you need to solve the issue. What exactly is not clear from the answer ? You need to inform Vuetify that the locale is changed - by setting `this.$vuetify.lang.current`

Answer (score 1):

When you change the locale in `i18n` you should also change it in Vuetify:

```js
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    locale: selectedLocale
  },
  mutations: {
    updateLocale(state, newLocale) {
      state.locale = newLocale
    }
  },
  actions: {
    changeLocale({ commit }, { newLocale, currentVueComponent }) {
      i18n.locale = newLocale
      currentVueComponent.$vuetify.lang.current = newLocale // <--- the important code
      commit('updateLocale', newLocale)
    }
  },
  plugins: [createPersistedState()]
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much! But I get an error....Cannot read $vuetify

Comment: You are sending `null` for the `currentVueComponent` argument.

Comment: And how do I change this? Do I need to change something inside my Vuetify.js?

Comment: You can change it like this - `this.$store.dispatch("changeLocale", {newLocale: "es", currentVueComponent: this})`

Comment: I really appreciate all your help but I'm getting more confused by each answer. :-) Where do I put `this.$store.dispatch("changeLocale", {newLocale: "es", currentVueComponent: this}) ` inside my vuetify.js?

Comment: If you provide a CodeSandbox or JSfiddle I can show you. Where are you calling your action for changing the locale ? From vuetify.js ?

Comment: I can't seem to get it working on codesandbox...all the code is on https://github.com/Webbiebloom/language